# Узнать имя видео файла

Tags: html5, видео, youtube

Как узнать имя видео файла с видео хостинга (например *youtube* или *vimeo.com*)?

Надо, чтобы видео с *youtube* воспроизводилось в моём *html5-video-плеере*. Одной ссылки не достаточно, необходимо указывать точное название видео файла, иначе плеер отказывается его воспроизводить.

Comment: Например: не могу понять почему не работает вот этот код? Что в нём не так?
`<video id="video2" width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRsGyueVLvQ" type="video/youtube">
</video>`

Comment: Вам стоит посмотреть в строну `youtibe api`.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRsGyueVLvQ - это не ссылка на видео-файл. Это ссылка на html-файл, в котором, при помощи JavaScript по фрагментам загружается видео.
Если вы хотите вставить видео с youtube на свой сайт, надо использовать iframe с ссылкой embed-версию видео. Например:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eRsGyueVLvQ"></iframe>
```